# Angular less scss mat.define-light-theme

Tags: angular, themes, less

I try to traduce this angular scss code in less but i failed :

```
$theme: mat.define-light-theme((
  color: (
    primary: $primary,
    accent: $accent,
    warn: $warn,
  )
));
```

i don't know how to traduce the "define-light-theme" function parameter. the angular documentation is too blur.
If anyone can help me?
Thank you for your advice

`@theme: mat.define-light-theme(( ^ Expected ')' got '('`

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simplified example of how you might define a theme in a `theme.less` file using Less

```css
@import '~@angular/material/theming';

@primary: #your-primary-color;//use your own color
@accent: #your-accent-color;
@warn: #your-warn-color;

$custom-theme: mat.define-light-theme((
  color: (
    primary: $primary,
    accent: $accent,
    warn: $warn
  )
));


@include angular-material-theme($custom-theme);
```

Make sure to check the specific version of Angular and Angular Material you are using.I think that this might help's you